# Добавление изображение в всплывающем окне PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Возможно ли добавление изображение в всплывающее окна `.setToolTip` на примере данного кода. Т.е. при наведении на изображение оно в всплываюшем окне отображалось в более большем масштабе

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Ex(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.image_label = QLabel()
        self.image_label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.button = QPushButton('открыть изображение')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_image)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.image_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.open_image()

    def open_image(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '//home', "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg *.gif)")[0]
        if file_name:
            file = open(file_name, "rb")
            with file:
                self.img_data = file.read()
                self.pixmap.loadFromData(self.img_data)
                self.image_label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
                self.image_label.setFixedSize(100, 50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Ex()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всплывающий tooltip'ы в Qt поддерживают обработку HTML тэгов. Поэтому изображение в tooltip можно добавить вставкой тэга `img` в текст самого tooltip'a.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Widget(Qt.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = Qt.QPushButton("Button")
        button.setToolTip('<img src="image.png">Image</img>')
        layout.addWidget(button)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```